# Video Streaming with quality control in spring-boot?

Tags: spring-boot, video-streaming

I am new in spring boot and web development. Can you please guide me on how I can make a video streaming server that automatically changes the quality of video with network speed?
My preferred technology is spring-boot, but you can guide me with node js as well.
I have searched on all web but could not find a satisfactory answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post whatever solution you have now and state the problems you encountered with it.